# Default value on select with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having troubles with setting default category to this script. I want by default to be listed only **Category 1** with one news in it insead of **All** but nothing I tried seem to work. Any ideas?

This is the full code with HTML and some CSS: https://codepen.io/NickyCDK/pen/lhaiz

```js
//Filter News
$('select#sort-news').change(function() {
 var filter = $(this).val()
 filterList(filter);
});

//News filter function
function filterList(value) {
 var list = $(".news-list .news-item");
 $(list).fadeOut("fast");
 if (value == "All") {
  $(".news-list").find("article").each(function (i) {
   $(this).delay(200).slideDown("fast");
  });
 } else {
  //Notice this *=" <- This means that if the data-category contains multiple options, it will find them
  //Ex: data-category="Cat1, Cat2"
  $(".news-list").find("article[data-category*=" + value + "]").each(function (i) {
   $(this).delay(200).slideDown("fast");
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a trigger

```
$('select#sort-news').trigger(filterList('Cat1'), 'click');
```